# Cant load data onto Jupyter docker

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, docker-machine, jupyter-console

This is probably a obvious question, but i cant find a direct answer anywhere.

I installed, docker and docker machine, no problems so far. 
After that, i pulled this [imaged](https://hub.docker.com/r/dash00/datascience-notebook-opencv/) based on jupyter/datascience-notebook docker. Supposedly, the only diffences is that it has Open CV installed.

Now, this is my first time using docker. I run the jupyter notebook using this command on bash:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd)/WD:/notebook dash00/datascience-notebook-opencv
```

This succeed in loading the jupyter notebook, it loads packages and works for every python command i try. For example, if a define functions and try them, they work.

The problem is that when i try to load data, for example:

```
Import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("/home/mario/WD/test.csv")
```

i get the following error: "OSError: File b'/home/mario/WD/train.csv' does not exist"
the same happens when i try to load any kind of file using any kind of package, including images using cv2

Am i referencing the path wrong? do i have to refer to a host machine?

Answer (score 1):

From your docker command, you mounted /home/mario/WD into the container as /notebook (as a host volume). Therefore inside your container, you would use:

```
Import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("/notebook/test.csv")
```

Comment: @abdoulsn `$(pwd)` expands to the current directory (assuming you are in a bash shell). The `pwd` command is likely short for print working directory.

Answer (score 1):

The `-v $(pwd)/WD:/notebook` argument is mounting the `$(pwd)/WD` directory on your host to `/notebook` in your container. If the directory that you issued `docker run …` from is `/home/mario`, then you would find `/home/mario/WD/test.csv` at `/notebook/test.csv` in the container.

```
Import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("/notebook/test.csv")
```

You can also mount more directories from your host into the container as appropriate.

Comment: No cigar. i tried 'docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd)/WD 05c3
' and problem persist. Any suggestion? perhaps some specific documentation on jupyter docker you can point me?